# How do I set up my rubygems environment correctly?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I have the following error when I try to run `shotgun` (this is more about the gem environment than this specific gem):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'shotgun' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/shotgun:22:in `<main>'
```

In other words, I think it is looking in the wrong area (I don't try to run on Mac OSX's Ruby.framework.

I had tried to remove what I thought was a symlink with `rm -rf ~` and it deleted a bunch of things.

I have the following as my RubyGems environment, and I just want to have my own, separate ruby gem installation directory, not dependent on Framework or Library.  **How do I do that?**

However, when I look at both the Ruby Executable and Installation Directory, both are in Library.

```
    RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-13
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/angelacode/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
```

Comment: you've deleted you [home dir](http://superuser.com/questions/158721/what-does-mean-in-terms-of-os-x-folders-directories)? I think the rubygems directory is the least of your problems right now...

Comment: The ~ keeps showing up as a subdirectory.